# submitting facebook app for permission of publish_actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

For using score api as it is mentioned it is require to take publish_actions permission as mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/

when I tried to add permission to my app it is giving error It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days.

I am making call
FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, PostCallBack, scoreData); in game (which is not working)

note that I am doing re-submission. any solution how can I submit facebook app for review for permission of publish_actions

Answer (score 0):

**Check List for you.**

1. Your Facebook Sdk integrate *properly* end?.  [Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/android/?locale=ko_EN)
2. Available to the general public. *Facebook dev page -> apps -> status&review -> switch your app status*
3. If your used to Facebook SDK for Unity ,  open **InteractiveConsole** scene checks work It.

Good luck :D

Comment: my app is available for general public so no issue for that

Comment: and when i run interactiveconsole example it printed this  sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"key_hash":"eqg4gM3ugBMpTtyiLcaD6+d5g1U=\n","user_id":"***********","expiration_timestamp":"1424071921","access_token":"CAAVV3KwuU6ABAKrLx8IOAKsHTUY8vSFcRBiCFKZAeWUytZCPa71vcTDzun2bVQ6HLuMsowmDiEZBD6gI6mnDfaWZBTuQLRnvJuIWUaXUFTeqkjXKDKR9TnzdpZCHw0GsNFZCgBU1nsZAp6qBPLinCQxIUp68C5YbsnE9M1ZBUkAHOlFlyrNVrXmSukzwjPJ0keOHc5GlKYfsRySdTkn3FF5QWoWkmNFL1niowZBXr1B2I37ZBJa1unuAtZBr6ZCniM6ASIZBvRUzjhWiCGTQZDZD","opened":true})
any help???

Comment: not allowing me to submit request for taking purmission of publish_actions

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and is fixed now. THe one and only thing you have to do is to login to facebook (inside your application, once the login action is called) with your admin username and password (not with your personal username) atleast once.

If both are the same then i dont think this issue will arise.

Let me know if this worked. THanks